# Create a new column by other column's value in data table in r

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data table like this

```
| x | y |
| - | - |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
```

And I need to create another column z based on the value of x : if its x>=1 and x<=3 then the value should be 1 else be 0

```
| x | y | z |
| - | - | - |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 |
```

I was trying to use `dt[, z:= ,]`
But I'm not sure how to add the conditions to the function

Comment: Use the `ifelse` function `dt[, z := ifelse(x >= 1 & x <= 3, 1, 0)]`. Or more directly coerce the logical condition to integer--TRUE will be 1, FALSE will be 0: `dt[, z := as.integer(x >= 1 & x <= 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ifelse` function

```
dt[, z := ifelse(x >= 1 & x <= 3, 1, 0)]
```

Or, more directly, you can coerce the logical condition to integer--TRUE will be 1, FALSE will be 0:

```
dt[, z := as.integer(x >= 1 & x <= 3)]
```

Or using `data.table`'s helper `%between%`:

```
dt[, z := as.integer(x %between% c(1, 3))]
```